# Getting a KeyError when trying to run De-dupe

Tags: python, pandas, python-dedupe

Hi I'm new to Python and I've no clue how to fix the following error:

I've a data frame with around 2 million records & 20 columns of stores data, I am grouping the stores by State and trying to run dedupe_dataframe on each state after training it on one.

Here is how my code looks (np is numpy, dp is pandas pandas_dedupe):

```
#Read Store Data
stores = pd.read_csv("storefile.csv",sep = ",", encoding= 'latin1',dtype=str)

#There was /t in the first column so removing that
stores= stores.replace('\t','', regex=True)
stores= stores.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

#Getting a lowercase state list
states=list(stores.State.str.lower().unique())

#Grouping Data by States
state_data= {state: stores[stores.State.str.lower()==state] for state in states}

#Running De-Dupe for state Ohio ('oh')
dp.dedupe_dataframe(state_data['oh'], ['StoreBannerName','Address','City','State'])
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
    importing data ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-37-e2ed10256338> in <module>
----> 1 dp.dedupe_dataframe(state_data['oh'], ['StoreBannerName','Address','City','State'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_dedupe\dedupe_dataframe.py in
dedupe_dataframe(df, field_properties, canonicalize, config_name,
recall_weight, sample_size)
    211     # train or load the model
    212     deduper = _train(settings_file, training_file, data_d, field_properties,
--> 213                      sample_size)
    214 
    215     # ## Set threshold

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_dedupe\dedupe_dataframe.py in
_train(settings_file, training_file, data, field_properties, sample_size)
     58         # To train dedupe, we feed it a sample of records.
     59         sample_num = math.floor(len(data) * sample_size)
---> 60         deduper.sample(data, sample_num)
     61 
     62         # If we have training data saved from a previous run of dedupe,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dedupe\api.py in sample(self, data,
sample_size, blocked_proportion, original_length)
    836                                                  sample_size,
    837                                                  original_length,
--> 838                                                  index_include=examples)
    839 
    840         self.active_learner.mark(examples, y)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dedupe\labeler.py in __init__(self,
data_model, data, blocked_proportion, sample_size, original_length,
index_include)
    401         data = core.index(data)
    402 
--> 403         self.candidates = super().sample(data, blocked_proportion, sample_size)
    404 
    405         random_pair = random.choice(self.candidates)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dedupe\labeler.py in sample(self, data,
blocked_proportion, sample_size)
     50         return [(data[k1], data[k2])
     51                 for k1, k2
---> 52                 in blocked_sample_keys | random_sample_keys]
     53 
     54 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dedupe\labeler.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     49 
     50         return [(data[k1], data[k2])
---> 51                 for k1, k2
     52                 in blocked_sample_keys | random_sample_keys]
     53 

KeyError: 2147550487
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer that solved your question? This would mark the question as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Swap the following line:

```py
#Running De-Dupe for state Ohio ('oh')
dp.dedupe_dataframe(state_data['oh'], ['StoreBannerName','Address','City','State'])
```

**WITH**

```py
#Running De-Dupe for state Ohio ('oh')
state_data['oh'].dedupe_dataframe(subset = ['StoreBannerName','Address','City','State'], keep='first')
```

#### Reference

- [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: @NeerajGrover If you think this answered what you had asked for and was helpful, please consider **`upvoting`** and **`accepting`** the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got a `KeyError` as well.
I used this code example:

https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe-examples/tree/master/record_linkage_example

I had changed some of the code and I had forgotten to remove `data_matching_learned_settings` file before running it again.

Another reason you might get this error, especially with the first column, is that your file could contain a BOM (Byte Order Mark) in the first character.

See this for how to remove a BOM:
[VS Code: How to save UTF-8 without BOM in Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64184665/vs-code-how-to-save-utf-8-without-bom-in-mac)