# VS Code: How to save UTF-8 without BOM in Mac?

Tags: php, macos, visual-studio-code, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I'm currently working on a project which locally works just fine but once I upload it to my hoster's server it just throws errors. My hoster says that it's the fault of BOMs inside the file.
How do I get rid of them inside VS Code or Brackets?

Comment: Any BOM inside comes from included files - Byte Order Mark is at start always. Get rid with this included - save them without the BOM

Comment: So if I include a file BOMs appear? I include one file. I saved both files (the one that includes and the included) without BOM now and the error is gone. But the problem doesn't get solved in another file.

Answer (score 9):

In VS Code, the encoding information can usually be found at the bottom right of the editor window, along with end-of-line sequence (LF, CRLF) and language mode (PHP, JavaScript, etc.).

If the text file includes a BOM (Byte Order Mark) at its very beginning, `UTF-8 with BOM` should be displayed down there in a clickable area. Mouse-clicking on it will bring an `Action` pop-up menu at the top of the window, coming with two items:

- `Reopen with Encoding`
- `Save with Encoding`

Select the `Save with Encoding` action, then `UTF-8` in the next `Encoding` pop-up menu. This will get rid of the embedded BOM for the current file.

This is referenced in the VS Code online documentation: [Basic Editing > File Encoding Support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_file-encoding-support)

Comment: Oh, already saw that but didn't know if offered more options when I click. Anyways, in my normal page (https://caddit.ncls.nl) the error is gone but it still doesn't do what it's supposed to do (redirect you to login).

The login page (https://caddit.ncls.nl/login) still has problems with "headers already sent", which the BOM removing normally should fix according to my hoster.